# How to avoid white spaces in textbox in devexpress textbox mode?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using DevExtreme, I want to remove whitespaces in textbox. Can you tell me how to do it?

```
items.AddSimple().ColSpan(15).DataField("Email").Label(x => x.Visible(false))
     .Editor(x => x.TextBox().Name("Email").ID("emailTextBox").Placeholder("Email")
     .Mode(DevExtreme.AspNet.Mvc.TextBoxMode.Email))
     .ValidationRules(v => v.AddEmail()).ValidationRules(v => v.AddRequired());
```